# Does uiautomator work on android wearable?

Tags: android, ui-automation, wear-os, android-uiautomator

Does uiautomator work on android wearable ? Is there any automation methods available for android wearable?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say that it does work. I think it doesn't really matter the type of the device as long as it runs android and it has an UI. But you have an easy way to find out: try it :)

Comment: I tried the easy way. Unfortunately it crashes often. Not sure something wrong with my gear OS. thanks~